# How do I make my dashboard table dynamic, real-time, reflect changes in mySQL database automatically?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend, backend

FrontEnd Code

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Navbar from "../Navbar/Navbar.js";
import BarChart from "../BarChart/BarChart";
import {
  Chart,
  Tooltip,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  Title,
  LineController,
  LineElement,
  PointElement,
} from "chart.js";
import Card from "../Card/Card.js";
import CardHeader from "../Card/CardHeader.js";
import CardIcon from "../Card/CardIcon.js";
import CardBody from "../Card/CardBody";
import CardFooter from "../Card/CardFooter";
import GridItem from "../Grid/GridItem.js";
import GridContainer from "../Grid/GridContainer.js";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Table from "../Table/Table";
import Icon from "@material-ui/core/Icon";
import Danger from "../Typography/Danger.js";
import Warning from "@material-ui/icons/Warning";
import DateRange from "@material-ui/icons/DateRange";
import Update from "@material-ui/icons/Update";
import Store from "@material-ui/icons/Store";
import LocalOffer from "@material-ui/icons/LocalOffer";
import Accessibility from "@material-ui/icons/Accessibility";
// import { Icon, InlineIcon } from '@iconify/react';
import contentCopy from "@iconify-icons/mdi/content-copy";
import styles from "../../assets/jss/material-dashboard/views/dashboardStyle.js";

import Map from "../Map/map";

import Axios from "axios"; //axios library to make requests to api
import "./Home.css";
import ReactPaginate from "react-paginate";
import ReactExport from "react-data-export";

const ExcelFile = ReactExport.ExcelFile;
const ExcelSheet = ReactExport.ExcelFile.ExcelSheet;

Chart.register(
  Tooltip,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  Title,
  LineController,
  LineElement,
  PointElement
);

var i = 0;

function Home(props) {
  //make an axios request to get intents data from database
  const [intentsList, setintentsList] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/intents").then((response) => {
      setintentsList(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const [customerList, setCustomerList] = useState([]); //store all that information of the database in a list
  //make an axios request to get information from database
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/customers").then((response) => {
      setCustomerList(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const updateCustomerContacted = (ID) => {
    Axios.put("http://localhost:3001/update", {
      contacted: newContacted,
      ID: ID,
    }).then((response) => {
      setCustomerList(
        customerList.map((val) => {
          const dateStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocaleDateString(
            "en-CA"
          );
          const timeStr = new Date(
            val.latest_time_of_visit
          ).toLocaleTimeString();
          const dateTime = `${dateStr} ${timeStr}`;

          return val.ID == ID
            ? {
                ID: val.ID,
                name: val.name,
                email: val.email,
                counts_of_visit: val.counts_of_visit,
                latest_time_of_visit: dateTime,
                contacted: newContacted,
              }
            : val;
        })
      );
    });
  };
  //function to format the datetime to correct format
  const formatDatetime = (datetime) => {
    const dateStr = new Date(datetime).toLocaleDateString("en-CA");
    const timeStr = new Date(datetime).toLocaleTimeString();
    return `${dateStr} ${timeStr}`;
  };

  //function to format serial number manually

  //delete function
  const deleteCustomer = (ID) => {
    Axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/stats/delete/${ID}`).then(
      (response) => {
        setCustomerList(
          customerList.filter((val) => {
            return val.ID != ID;
          })
        );
      }
    );
  };

  //pagination
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(0);
  const customersPerPage = 5; //change this number according to desired number of rows in a page
  const pagesVisited = pageNumber * customersPerPage;
  const displayCustomers = customerList
    .slice(pagesVisited, pagesVisited + customersPerPage)
    .map((val, key) => {
      const dateStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocaleDateString(
        "en-CA"
      );
      const timeStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocaleTimeString();
      const dateTime = `${dateStr} ${timeStr}`;
      const my_serial = key + pageNumber * customersPerPage;
      return (
        <tr>
          {/*}
          <td>{val.ID}</td>
      */}
          <td>{my_serial + 1}</td>
          <td>{val.name}</td>
          <td>{val.email}</td>
          <td>{val.counts_of_visit}</td>
          <td>{dateTime}</td>
          <td>{val.contacted}</td>
          <td>
            <select
              onChange={(event) => {
                setNewContacted(event.target.value);
              }}
            >
              <option value="" selected disabled hidden>
                Select Yes/No
              </option>
              <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
              <option value="No">No</option>
            </select>
            <button
              className="btn btn-primary"
              onClick={() => {
                updateCustomerContacted(val.ID);
              }}
            >
              Update
            </button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button
              className="btn btn-danger"
              onClick={() => {
                deleteCustomer(val.ID);
              }}
            >
              Delete
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  //to account for the fact that total number of customers cannot be divided equally among the pages
  const pageCount = Math.ceil(customerList.length / customersPerPage);
  //page change
  const changePage = ({ selected }) => {
    setPageNumber(selected);
  };

  //update contacted column
  const [newContacted, setNewContacted] = useState(0);

  {
    /*}
      const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(1);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        fetch("/time")
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((data) => {
            setCurrentTime(data.time);
          });
      }, []);
    */
  }

  //export to csv function

  const DataSet = [
    {
      columns: [
        {
          title: "S/N",
          style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } },
          width: { wpx: 125 },
        }, // width in pixels
        {
          title: "Customer Information",
          style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } },
          width: { wpx: 250 },
        }, // width in pixels
        {
          title: "Customer Email",
          style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } },
          width: { wpx: 250 },
        }, // width in pixels
        {
          title: "Counts of Visit",
          style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } },
          width: { wpx: 175 },
        }, // width in pixels
        {
          title: "Latest Time of Visit",
          style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } },
          width: { wpx: 250 },
        }, // width in pixels
        {
          title: "Contacted?",
          style: { font: { sz: "18", bold: true } },
          width: { wpx: 250 },
        }, // width in pixels
      ],
      data: customerList.map((val, key) => [
        { value: key + 1, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
        { value: val.name, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
        { value: val.email, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
        { value: val.counts_of_visit, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
        {
          value: formatDatetime(val.latest_time_of_visit),
          style: { font: { sz: "14" } },
        },
        { value: val.contacted, style: { font: { sz: "14" } } },
      ]),
    },
  ];

  const useStyles = makeStyles(styles);
  const classes = useStyles;

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <GridContainer>
        <GridItem xs={12} sm={6} md={6}>
          {" "}
          {/*width for different screen sizes*/}
          <Card>
            <CardHeader color="warning" stats icon>
              <CardIcon color="danger">
                <h4 className={classes.cardTitleWhite}>Product Statistics</h4>
                {/* <Icon>content_copy</Icon> */}
              </CardIcon>
              <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Used Space</p>
              <h3 className={classes.cardTitle}>
                49/50 <small>GB</small>
              </h3>
            </CardHeader>
            <CardBody>
              <BarChart />
            </CardBody>
            <CardFooter stats>
              <div className={classes.stats}>
                <Danger>
                  <Warning />
                </Danger>
                <a href="#pablo" onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}></a>
              </div>
            </CardFooter>
          </Card>
        </GridItem>
        <GridItem xs={12} sm={6} md={6}>
          <Card>
            <CardHeader color="dark" stats icon>
              <CardIcon color="dark">
                {/* <Store /> */}
                <h4 className={classes.cardTitleWhite}>Locations</h4>
              </CardIcon>

              <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Revenue</p>
              <h3 className={classes.cardTitle}>$34,245</h3>
            </CardHeader>
            <CardBody>
              <Map />
            </CardBody>
            <CardFooter stats>
              <div className={classes.stats}>
                <DateRange />
              </div>
            </CardFooter>
          </Card>
        </GridItem>
        {/* <GridItem xs={12} sm={6} md={6}>
                    <Card>
                        <CardHeader color="danger" stats icon>
                        <CardIcon color="danger">
                            <Icon>info_outline</Icon>
                        </CardIcon>
                        <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Fixed Issues</p>
                        <h3 className={classes.cardTitle}>75</h3>
                        </CardHeader>
                        <CardFooter stats>
                        <div className={classes.stats}>
                            <LocalOffer />
                            
                        </div>
                        </CardFooter>
                    </Card>
                    </GridItem>
                    <GridItem xs={12} sm={6} md={6}>
                    <Card>
                        <CardHeader color="info" stats icon>
                        <CardIcon color="info">
                            <Accessibility />
                        </CardIcon>
                        <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Followers</p>
                        <h3 className={classes.cardTitle}>+245</h3>
                        </CardHeader>
                        <CardFooter stats>
                        <div className={classes.stats}>
                            <Update />
                           
                        </div>
                        </CardFooter>
                    </Card>
                    </GridItem> */}
      </GridContainer>

      <GridContainer>
        <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
          <Card>
            <CardHeader color="warning">
              <h4 className={classes.cardTitleWhite}>Customer Information</h4>
              {/*}
              <p className={classes.cardCategoryWhite}>
                Visitors since 16th May, 2021
              </p>
                */}
            </CardHeader>
            <CardBody>
              <div className="dashboardcontainer">
                <div className="container"></div>
                <table className="customertable">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      {/*}
                      <th>S/N</th>
              */}
                      <th>S/N</th>
                      <th>Customer Name</th>
                      <th>Customer Email</th>
                      <th>Counts of Visit</th>
                      <th>Latest Time of Visit</th>
                      <th>Contacted?</th>
                      <th>Edit Contacted</th>
                      <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>{displayCustomers}</tbody>
                </table>
                <ReactPaginate
                  previousLabel={"Previous"}
                  nextLabel={"Next"}
                  pageCount={pageCount}
                  onPageChange={changePage}
                  containerClassName={"paginationBttns"}
                  pageLinkClassName={"paginationNumber"}
                  previousLinkClassName={"previousBttn"}
                  nextLinkClassName={"nextBttn"}
                  disabledClassName={"paginationDisabled"}
                  activeClassName={"paginationActive"}
                />
                <ExcelFile
                  filename="Customer Information"
                  element={
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      className="btn btn-success float-right m-3"
                    >
                      Export to Excel
                    </button>
                  }
                >
                  <ExcelSheet
                    dataSet={DataSet}
                    name="Customer Information Report"
                  ></ExcelSheet>
                </ExcelFile>
              </div>
              {/*}
              <Table
                tableHeaderColor="warning"
                tableHead={["ID", "Name", "Salary", "Country"]}
                tableData={[
                  ["1", "Dakota Rice", "$36,738", "Niger"],
                  ["2", "Minerva Hooper", "$23,789", "Curaçao"],
                  ["3", "Sage Rodriguez", "$56,142", "Netherlands"],
                  ["4", "Philip Chaney", "$38,735", "Korea, South"],
                ]}
              />
            */}
            </CardBody>
          </Card>
        </GridItem>
      </GridContainer>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

BACKEND CODE
BACKEND CODE
BACKEND CODE
BACKEND CODE

```
//set up express server
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
//set up sql server
const mysql = require("mysql");
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
//create a variable called db to make your SQL Statements
const db = mysql.createConnection({
  user: "",
  host: "",
  password: "",
  database: "",
});

//GET REQUEST to database to retrieve customers information from database
app.get("/customers", (req, res) => {
  db.query("SELECT * FROM customer_info", (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
});

//Update customers
app.put("/update", (req, res) => {
  const ID = req.body.ID;
  const contacted = req.body.contacted;

  db.query(
    "UPDATE customer_info SET contacted = ? WHERE ID = ?",
    [contacted, ID],
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.send(result);
      }
    }
  );
});

//Delete customers
app.delete("/stats/delete/:ID", (req, res) => {
  const ID = req.params.ID;

  db.query("DELETE FROM customer_info WHERE ID = ?", ID, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
});

//api call to pull intents data
app.get("/intents", (req, res) => {
  db.query("SELECT * FROM data_analytics", (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
});

//check if backend server is running
app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log("Your server is running on port 3001");
});
```

HELLO SO HOW CAN I make my dashboard table generated be real-time --> meaning to say every time there is a change to mySQL database be it CRUD operations, read, create, update or delete, the table will automatically refresh it self so multiple users can use it at the same time and see the changes in real time

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the built-in index in your `map` function?

Of course, you'll need to know the current page and the number of items to display per page, but looking at your variables, I assume you do.

Example:

```
myArray.map((val, idx) => {
    const my_serial = idx + (pageNumber * customersPerPage)
  })
```

EDIT: To add more details:

```
  const [displayCustomers, setDisplayCustomers] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const displayCust = customerList
      .slice(pagesVisited, pagesVisited + customersPerPage)
      .map((val, key) => {
        const dateStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocaleDateString(
          'en-CA'
        );
        const timeStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocaleTimeString();
        const dateTime = `${dateStr} ${timeStr}`;
        return (
          <tr>
            {/*}
          <td>{val.ID}</td>
      */}
            <td>{i++}</td>
            <td>{val.name}</td>
            <td>{val.email}</td>
            <td>{val.counts_of_visit}</td>
            <td>{dateTime}</td>
            <td>{val.contacted}</td>
            <td>
              <select
                onChange={(event) => {
                  setNewContacted(event.target.value);
                }}
              >
                <option value="" selected disabled hidden>
                  Select Yes/No
                </option>
                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="No">No</option>
              </select>
              <button
                className="btn btn-primary"
                onClick={() => {
                  updateCustomerContacted(val.ID);
                }}
              >
                Update
              </button>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button
                className="btn btn-danger"
                onClick={() => {
                  deleteCustomer(val.ID);
                }}
              >
                Delete
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        );
      });
    setDisplayCustomers(displayCust);
  }, [customerList]);
```

You can either do this, and then in your `<tbody>{displayCustomers}</tbody>` just map on displayCustomers and return directly the value, or you can move all this code directly inside your returned HTML code, saving the allocation of an array of components.

Comment: I am not using the build-in index because when I delete a row the serial numbers don't show in consecutive order so for example If I delete row 2 my table will show s/n 1 then s/n 3 and so on so forth. If I followed your code how can I add it to my exported excel as well?

Comment: Well, that's because you'd need to put your code in a `useEffect`. You want this code to reload every time a change has been made to `displayCustomers`.

Comment: which use effect hook do I include in my code

Comment: Hi sorry may I know which part u changed

Comment: Starting from your `//pagination` comment, there's a line starting with `const displayCustomers = customerList`. I just moved this whole line/slicing/mapping thing in a useEffect.

Comment: thank! I edited my code accordingly to your comments but It still doesn't work, you can refer to above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233129/discussion-between-gaetan-boyals-and-max).